# Rewrite rule not loading css and scripts

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently i have this store files structure:

`www.mysite.com/store` as the index for the store (store.php)
(already working without .php) where i have all the items listed

Then i have the subcategories file as `subcategories.php`

Finally my products file `product_detail.php`

This is what i have done so far:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subcategories\.php\?subcatid=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/store/%1? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^store/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ subcategories.php?subcatid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

And made a php script to change the id for the name in the url following this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['subcatid'])){
    if(is_numeric($_GET['subcatid'])){ //Check if the input is all numeric
        //Grab the username from database
        //Redirect user to site.com/user/$username
    }
}
```

So, i final example is like
`www.mysite.com/store/furniture`  <- subcatid

Where is listing all the the products from that subcategory.

It's loading ok but styles and js are missing, how can i correct this and what approach should i take to each subcategory product with htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the top of your html in the `head` section

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/store/" />
```

Replace with your site. This is providing your assets are in a sub directory of `store` otherwise if the assets is in a directory in the root use this.

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

Comment: Is there any other way with htaccess to do it?

Comment: I don't get why people try to do everything with .htaccess. It's trying to use the relative path because of the rewrites. It's not an htaccess problem. You either need to use `/` at the beginning your of your paths, e.g. `/path/to/style.css`, use absolute paths for your assets or the base tag. All of which is something you control in your html.